# Share article via email form rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, email, simple-form

I have looked around but can't decide on the best way for a 'share via email' form in my rails app without using services such as 'add this' etc...

I want to create a form thats takes 1 email. When submitted it will send an email to that email with a link to the current article and some other pre determined text.

Any way I can do this within my articles controller? Just with a simple method? If so what would the form look like?

I know I could use simple form but I don't want to create a separate controller just for sharing via email.

**NB**
I know how to handle the sending of the emails etc.. Im just unsure of the best was to interact with the controller via the view. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new controller? If you want a RESTful app then you should create a new shares_controller with a new/create (or if form is a partial then just a create). If you don't care about RESTful then just throw an extra method in the articles controller with a form in a partial, it's just a standard form.

Comment: To be honest I was scared at cluttering up the controllers folder but I guess it is best practice. I was also curious on how to do it without a controller. Im guessing it just involved a new method in articles controller and then calling something like `<% form_tag(share_email_path, :method => :post) do %>` ?

Comment: Pretty much, with an ugly custom route. If your controllers folder is getting large, consider namespacing them - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing